# Is it possible to change the text of the Products menu link from WooCommerce on the Wordpress Admin Panel?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

we could change the parent one that says Products, and we change that name to something else, but not the children.

Is it possible?

[image]

Thank you so much

Comment: Why do you want to change WooCommerce core labels?

Comment: Instead of products we have documents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this. First is to translate it via the PO/MO files provided.

The other way You can change the labels on the filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_post_type_product', 'custom_post_type_label_woo' );

function custom_post_type_label_woo( $args ){
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => __( 'Elements', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'Element', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Elements', 'Admin menu name', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'add_new'            => __( 'Add Element', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Tour', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'edit'               => __( 'Edit Element', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Element', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Element', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'view'               => __( 'View Element', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Element', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Elements', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Elements found', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Elements found in trash', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'parent'             => __( 'Parent Element', 'your-custom-plugin' )
    );

    $args['labels'] = $labels;
    $args['description'] = __( 'This is where you can add new tours to your store.', 'your-custom-plugin' );
    return $args;
}
```